# Access a class inside its static methods

Tags: javascript, typeerror, es6-class

I am building a simple `class`. My question is:

**How to access a class method, or `this` for that matter, inside a static class method?**

When trying to access `this` inside a `static` method like this:

```js
const { ProductsCollection } = require('../utils/Collection')
let modeledCollection = ProductsCollection.mapToModel(legacy)
```

I get a **TypeError**:  `this.generateModel is not a function`. Here is my class:

```js
class ProductsCollection {
    generateModel () {
        let model = { name: 'testing' }
        return model
    }

    static mapToModel (legacy) {
        if (!isObject(legacy))
            return legacy

        let current = this.generateModel() // Here!!!
        for (let key in legacy) {
          // some code...
        }
        return current
    }
}

module.exports = { ProductsCollection }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't. `static` means *no instance*, so you can't access instance properties.

Comment: my bad, posted it to fast.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Still, if I am posting an issue here is because I am confused about something, so the whole point is to correct and learn, don't you think?

Comment: @kamatheuska - The point is simply that the question was unclear with the syntax error. You've fixed that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to access a class method, or this for that matter, inside a static class method?

The only way to access instance information from a `static` method is to create an instance (or receive one as a parameter, or close over one [which would be very odd], etc.; e.g., you need an instance). This is the point of `static` methods: They aren't associated with an instance of the class, they're associated with the constructor function.

Your `generateModel` method, as shown, doesn't use the instance either, so it may make sense for it to be `static` as well. Then you'd access it via `this.generateModel` (assuming `mapToModel` is called via `ProductsCollection.mapToModel`) or `ProductsCollection.generateModel` (if you don't want to make that assumption):

```js
class ProductsCollection {
  static generateModel() {
    return {name: "testing"};
  }
  
  static mapToModel(legacy) {
    return this.generateModel();
    // or `return ProductsCollection.generateModel();` if you want to use
    // `ProductsCollection` specifically and not be friendly
    // to subclasses
  }
}
console.log(ProductsCollection.mapToModel({}));
```

Or if `generateModel` need instance information, you might use `new ProductsCollection` (or `new this`) in your `mapToModel` to create an instance, then access `generateModel` on that instance.

```js
class ProductsCollection {
  generateModel() {
    return {name: "testing"};
  }
  
  static mapToModel(legacy) {
    const instance = new this();
    // or `const instance = new ProductsCollection();` if you want
    // to use `ProductsCollection` specifically and not be friendly
    // to subclasses
    return instance.generateModel();
  }
}
console.log(ProductsCollection.mapToModel({}));
```

Comment: The first snippet seems like the simplest way to go on my case. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access an instance method as it were a static one. This is a classic error. The only way you can use an instance method inside a static one is if you have an instance of the class available (hence the name "instance method").

Usually you are making some mistake in how you are deciding what should be static and what not...without thinking much I can just suggest making the `generateModel` method static. Another way would be to remove the `generateModel` method completely and incorporate it's behaviour inside a constructor. It really depends on what your needs are.

Just remember that if you are accessing a non static property inside a method then it probably should not be static.